# Speed of loading some images from one source

Tags: html, image

For example I have three images with the same source like this:

```
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="250" height="300"> 
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600"> 
<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="1000" height="1200">
```

Would they beeing loading the same amount of time like three images with different sources?

Comment: Very unlikely. Why do you think that?

Comment: I am not sure if this is on topic.  However, the browser would normally cache the image as it loads so there will be only one access.

Comment: @RohitGupta

Yes, it's on topic — I asked about cache. Thank you